# Get the last element of a Java collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection, and I want to get the last element of it. What's the most straighforward and fast way to do so?

One solution is to first [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()), and then return the last element of the array. Are there any other better ones?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not very efficient solution, but working one:

```
public static <T> T getFirstElement(final Iterable<T> elements) {
    return elements.iterator().next();
}

public static <T> T getLastElement(final Iterable<T> elements) {
    T lastElement = null;

    for (T element : elements) {
        lastElement = element;
    }

    return lastElement;
}
```

Comment: It actually is quite efficient. In fact, as efficient as it can be without to trying to cast the iterable to any more specific type (well, `List`).

Answer (score 66):

A `Collection` is not a necessarily ordered set of elements so there may not be a concept of the "last" element.  If you want something that's ordered, you can use a `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet` which has a `last()` method.  Or you can use a `List` and call `mylist.get(mylist.size()-1);`

If you *really* need the last element you should use a `List` or a `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet`.  But if all you have is a `Collection` and you really, really, *really* need the last element, you could use `toArray()` or you could use an `Iterator` and iterate to the end of the list.

For example:

```
public Object getLastElement(final Collection c) {
    final Iterator itr = c.iterator();
    Object lastElement = itr.next();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        lastElement = itr.next();
    }
    return lastElement;
}
```

Comment: I only have collection available, I don't know it's fundamental type be it array, list or others. So, to use SortedSet, I would have to firstly construct the SortedSet using the collection, and then do the rest of work. Will that be expensive?

Comment: @tom It would probably be O(n*lg(n)) to construct the `SortedSet` (if you constructed it all at once).  So depending on how many items you expect to have, it could be rather expensive.  Usually, if your underlying type is ordered, you can at least cast it to a `List` even if you don't know what type of `List` it is.

Comment: Thanks @Jack, assume my data is sorted when returning to me, as they are the case, will there be another solution?

Comment: @tom If you're guaranteed to get sorted data, you can *probably* assume the Collection's type implements `SortedSet` or at least `List`.  However, if you still can make no assumptions about the underlying type, then you're stuck with the API exposed by `Collection` which won't make it easy to find the last element as a `Collection` doesn't have a concept of a last element.  Thus, you'll need to iterate through and find the last element yourself (`toArray` works fine as well assuming you don't have any concerns about memory usage).

Comment: This throws a NullPointerException when an empty collection is given. Use `Object lastElement = null;` instead to return null in case of an empty collection.

Comment: can also make the method static too

Comment: Any reason to use the iterator instead of converting to array and getting the last index?

Comment: @SinaMadani it takes less additional space to use the iterator.

Comment: "last" have nothing to do with sorting as your said List(array) can have its last element. It just is java design defect

Comment: This one has the drawback of the reallocation of the `lastElement` variable every iteration of the while loop, but works as spected.

Answer (score 61):

[`Iterables.getLast`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getLast-java.lang.Iterable-) from Google Guava.
It has some optimization for `List`s and `SortedSet`s too.

Comment: Not null safe. You get NPE if your collection is null.

Comment: If your anything is null you will get an NPE in Java. Check it.

Comment: @DenisS Which is a feature of the implementation, and by design. [Guava: Using and avoiding null](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).  Besides, a null collection doesn't exist, so it doesn't have a last element.

Answer (score 16):

This should work without converting to List/Array:

```
collectionName.stream().reduce((prev, next) -> next).orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 10):

Well one solution could be:

```
list.get(list.size()-1)
```

Edit: You have to convert the collection to a list before maybe like this: new ArrayList(coll)

Comment: So I need to construct the list using the collection first. Performance wise, will that be different from toArray solution?

Comment: If all you are doing is getting the last element it is more efficient to use toArray() than build an ArrayList

Comment: Question mentions it is a collection not a list. Now, for converting it to a list just to have the last element is a bad solution and can lead to performance bottlenecks if you have large collections. Use Guava's Iterable.getLast method instead.

Comment: If you have to bring yourself to convert it (which will copy it), you might as well just use one of the iterative solutions...

Answer (score 6):

A reasonable solution would be to use an iterator if you don't know anything about the underlying Collection, but do know that there is a "last" element. This isn't always the case, not all Collections are ordered.

```
Object lastElement = null;

for (Iterator collectionItr = c.iterator(); collectionItr.hasNext(); ) {
  lastElement = collectionItr.next();
}
```

Comment: Correct, I don't know the underlying type of the collection. But if it's a big collection, then it'll be a O(N) solution. I am essentially looking for a O(1) solution.

Comment: That isn't possible. Consider trying to get the last element of a singly linked list. That operation *has* to be O(n), there is no generic O(1) answer.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary non-empty collection, the following gets the last element by streaming over the collection, skipping everything but the last element:

```java
c.stream().skip(c.size() - 1).findFirst().orElseThrow()
```

If the collection is of a type that provides a built-in mechanism to efficiently get the last element (in particular, the [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) types — `List`, `SortedSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, etc.), this will generally be much less efficient than using the mechanism provided by that type.  If you don't know the `Collection` type ahead of time, but want to optimize for this very common case, you could do so:

```java
Collection<Integer> c = getCollection();

String last = c instanceof SequencedCollection<String> s 
        ? s.getLast()
        : c.stream().skip(c.size() - 1).findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `last()` or `first()` method in a Collection interface. For getting the last method, you can either do `get(size() - 1)` on a List or reverse the List and do `get(0)`. I don't see a need to have `last()` method in any Collection API unless you are dealing with `Stacks` or `Queues`

Comment: Collection doesn't have a get method neither.

Comment: Sure! I meant the List implementation of the Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a for-each loop:

```
Collection<X> items = ...;
X last = null;
for (X x : items) last = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Iterable convert to stream and find last element

```
 Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three").iterator();

 Iterable<String> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;


 String last = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null);
```