# how to conveniently get first element or last element from LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I hava a structure Map :

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I don't know the key, but I want to pick up the first element and the last element, how can I achieve  conveniently.

Comment: you mean the key or the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936462/java-linkedhashmap-get-first-or-last-entry

Comment: have a look at it .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936462/java-linkedhashmap-get-first-or-last-entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this:

```
    Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 2.0);
    map.put("two", 12.0);
    map.put("three", 44.0);
    String lKeyFirst = null;
    String lKeyLast = null;
    if (!map.isEmpty()){
      lKeyFirst = map.keySet().iterator().next();
      for(String key : map.keySet()){
        lKeyLast = key;
      }
      System.out.println("First key: " +lKeyFirst);
      System.out.println("Last key: " +lKeyLast);
    }
```

Output:

> First key: one
>
> Last key: three

of course `isEmpty` is never false in this case.

EDIT:

```
@Test
public void testMapOneValue() {
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("one", 2.0);
String lKeyFirst = null;
String lKeyLast = null;
if (!map.isEmpty()){
  lKeyFirst = map.keySet().iterator().next();
  for(String key : map.keySet()){
    lKeyLast = key;
  }
  System.out.println("First key: " +lKeyFirst);
  System.out.println("Last key: " +lKeyLast);
}
}
```

Output:

> First key: one
>
> Last key: one

Answer (score 2):

Getting the first is easy - request an `iterator` and take it's `next`.

```
// Needs null checks etc.
String first = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

Getting the last is covered in [Java get last element of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360785/java-get-last-element-of-a-collection).

Comment: or [use reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33960155/829571) :-)