# I am trying to get the last date element in a set, however It keeps returning the first one?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, set, key

Below is my code, I get the keys of my Map and then I iterate through them in order to get the last date, However it does not appear to get the last date. The values on this line `Set<Date> keys = date.keySet();` are 10.31.18 and 11.17.18. I would expect lastDate to equal 11.17.18 however it equals 10.31.18. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

```
Map<Date, List<Integer>> date = date(dates, noPupils);
                Set<Date> keys = date.keySet();
                for (Iterator<Date> it = keys.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Date lastDate = it.next();
```

Comment: the code seems to do the work, except there is redundant check for `it.hasNext()`

Comment: is your Map sorted or not sorted when you loop through it? `lastDate` returns the last date in the map order, not in map comparison.

Comment: Unsorted, Using just the Map Util from import java.util.Map;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360827/2838289). It already says:

> A `Collection` is not a necessarily ordered set

In your case it doesn't work [because](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html)

> The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on
>   the map's collection views return their elements. Some map
>   implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as
>   to their order; others, like the `HashMap` class, do not.

And apparently the `Map` `date` doesn't guarantee a specific order. This applies also to `Set<Date> keys = date.keySet()` [as this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet())

> Returns a `Set` view of the keys contained in this map ... is
>   backed by the map ...

But the solution is simple and comes out of the box:

```
Date lastDate = Collections.max(keys);
```

This works at once because `Date` implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LinkedHashMap or HashMap?

HashMap is not ordered Map.
LinkedHashMap is ordered Map which reserves insert order.

But I think you should use TreeSet which can sort your dates. As a result you don't need to care about what kind of Map :)